# How to check block adding characters if the input text is a special character?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview and it has some columns .
For example: Name|Age|Birthday
How can I filter the textbox so if the user is typing a special character it won't be added.

I know I need to use this : ^[^0-9a-zA-Z]*$ , but I don't know how.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OnBlur` and `OnKeyUp` Events of `TextBox`

### JavaScript

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function validation() {
        var txt = document.getElementById('<%= txt.ClientID%>').value;
        var regex = new RegExp('[^0-9a-zA-Z]+');
        while (txt.match(regex)) {
            if (txt.match(regex)[0] == "") break;
            txt = txt.replace(regex, '');
        }
        document.getElementById('<%= txt.ClientID%>').value = txt;
    }
    function onkeyUpEvent() {
        validation();
    }

    function onBlurEvent() {
        validation();
    }
</script>
```

### MarkUp

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" onkeyup="onkeyUpEvent();" 
                                           onblur="onBlurEvent();"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var lastValidValue;
input.addEventListener('keydown', function(evt) {
  // before change capture current value;
  lastValidValue = input.value;
}, false);
function onchange(evt) {
  if (/^[^0-9a-zA-Z]*$/.test(input.value))
  // if its valid, update preserved field.
    lastValidValue = input.value;
  else
  // otherwise revert to previous data.
    input.value = lastValidValue;
}
input.addEventLisenter('keyup', onchange, false);
input.addEventListener('change', onchange, false);
```

where input is a reference to your textbox.

Comment: Why `keydown`+`keyup` instead of `keypress`?

Comment: well, when keydown the content is not changed yet, so this is the right time to capture lastValidValue. when keyup, the change is committed to textbox, so it is the time to check its value. this solution works even for block change like paste or select-all then delete.